# How to separate elements angular2+?

Tags: angular, typescript, runtime-error

I'm trying to make a rating stars, but I need to display more than one rating stars using *ngFor like here!
[image]

But when I hover on first star, the first star in other stars also get balcked like this!

[image]

code is here ...

```
          <div *ngFor="let item of l">
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
              <a *ngIf="!boldStar" (click)="getRate($event)" (mouseover)="boldStar=true" (mouseleave)="boldStar = false" id=1><i class="far fa-star" id=2></i></a>
              <a *ngIf="boldStar" (click)="getRate($event)" (mouseover)="boldStar=true" (mouseleave)="boldStar = false" id=1><i class="fas fa-star" id=2></i></a>
              <a (click)="getRate($event)" id="2"><i [ngClass]="boldStar ? 'fas fa-star' : 'far fa-star'" id="2"></i></a>
              <a (click)="getRate($event)" id="3"><i [ngClass]="boldStar ? 'fas fa-star' : 'far fa-star'" id="3"></i></a>
              <a (click)="getRate($event)" id="4"><i class="far fa-star" id="4"></i></a>
              <a (click)="getRate($event)" id="5"><i class="far fa-star" id="5"></i></a>
          </div>
```

Comment: Could you share your typescript code?

Answer (score 0):

In your `*ngFor` you're saying "let item of l", which means in your class you have an array called `l`, which looks like it has 2 items in it (given you're getting 2 rows of stars in your example).

Inside your ngFor'd div, when you render the stars, you need to reference your `item` to decide if those stars, in that particular row, are bolded or not.

For example (and I'm just guessing, because I can't see your code...
`<i [ngClass]="item.boldStar1 ? 'fas fa-star' : 'far fa-star'">`

But what you do in your ternary check depends on the data type of each item...
For example, you might just store the number of stars as a `number` from 1-5.

```
<i [ngClass]="item >= 1 ? 'fas fa-star' : 'far fa-star'">
<i [ngClass]="item >= 2 ? 'fas fa-star' : 'far fa-star'">
<i [ngClass]="item >= 3 ? 'fas fa-star' : 'far fa-star'">
<i [ngClass]="item >= 4 ? 'fas fa-star' : 'far fa-star'">
<i [ngClass]="item >= 5 ? 'fas fa-star' : 'far fa-star'">
```

(also, side-note, avoid using the `id` attribute like that, as you have duplicates (eg. more than one 1, and 2, etc.) and you probably don't need it anyway).

But yes, if you want more help specific to your actual data model, feel free to post your class (typescript) code so we can see what you're trying to do :)

Comment: You could use an `*ngFor` loop to display the `i` elements.

Comment: @NightCabbage
This is the ts code, but I uploaded it on drive.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YcvxkPLSqNErLq0WS2v6_tltnoelq_vT/view?usp=sharing